# как убрать переключение языка на shift+space gnome

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome

У меня стоит ubuntu 20.04 gnome. Проблема заключается в том, что переключается язык ввода на комбинацию <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>, в процессе работы случайно эта комбинация нажимается много раз. Смотрел в gnome-tweak-tools и в стандартных настройках, нигде нет этой комбинации.
Где еще могут лежать настройки шорткатов?

Нашел, что еще настройки комбинаций могут быть здесь, пуодалял их все, предварительно сохранив бэкап копию, но комбинации <kbd>right alt</kbd> + <kbd>left alt</kbd>, <kbd>right shift</kbd> + <kbd>left shift</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> все еще переключают язык ввода
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg/Keyboard_configuration#Frequently_used_XKB_options

Я еще ставил XFCE ради интереса, там слой меняется исключительно на <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>. Может ли такое быть что это каким то образом повлияло на настройки раскладки гнома?

Comment: где в настройках клавиатуры они лежат

Comment: я не понял что вы написали

Comment: у клавиатуры есть настройки (где добавляется раскладки и проч.). Вот там устанавливается шорткат на переключение раскладки

Comment: Вы имеете в виду setting->keyboard shortcuts ? Если да, то там, как я писал в вопросе, не нашел такой комбинации. Там назачена только Super+Space [скриншот](https://c.radikal.ru/c06/2010/d1/0a31705c579e.png)

Comment: Тут вам показано, что назначено. А меняется в другом месте  - в настройках клавиатуры.

Comment: @mamol  Так вы на комбинацию нажмите и новую введите.

Comment: @Эникейщик Это единственная стандартная настройка клавиатуры, что я нашел.

Comment: @Ainar-G я и стирал, и ставил другую, но комбинации типа alt+alt, shift+shift, shift+space никуда не уходят.

Comment: @mamol Shift+Space у меня работает.  Alt+Alt и Shift+Shift, по-моему, не поддерживаются.

Comment: @Ainar-G  Alt+Alt и Shift+Shift меня, на самом деле не беспокоят, а вот Shift+Space дико бесит, а убрать не могу

Comment: @mamol, настроек xkb в третьегноме через гуйню ЕМНИП из коробки нет, а надлежащий способ их установить — `gnome-tweak-tool`.

Comment: @Fat-Zer вы про это? [gnome-tweak-tool_1](https://c.radikal.ru/c26/2010/a7/87480a0bc56b.png), [gnome-tweak-tool_2](https://a.radikal.ru/a35/2010/8a/75a372749216.png)

Comment: @mamol, да… если не работает и перезагрузка (или рестарт иксом) не помогает, то убедись, что нежелательный вариант присутствует в `setxkbmap -query`, а дальше придётся смотреть, кто его туда вносит...

Comment: @Fat-Zer похоже, тут только alt+shift и win+space  
`mamol@pc:~/projects$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us,ru,us
variant:    ,,
options:    grp_led:scroll,grp:alt_shift_toggle,caps:none,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,grp:win_space_toggle`

Comment: @mamol, и всё равно shift-space срабатывает для переключения раскладки? гм... странно... дальше я бы проверил через `xev`, что шифт и пробел — это действительно только шифт и пробел... в принципе возможно, что оно обрабатывается как шорткат, но это чтранная конфигурация...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, shift+space, l shift + r shift, l alt + r alt , alt + space, возможно это не полный список. [лог кнопушек](https://a.radikal.ru/a00/2010/83/5ba7ccdbce74.png) Систему поставил три дня назад

Comment: @mamol, гм... странно всё это звучит... у меня идеи пока кончились...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, а может быть из-за того, что до этого стояла kubuntu 20.04? у меня на разных разделах лежат /home и / .  /home не форматировал, а просто подключил к новой системе. Может какие-то настройки клавиатуры сохранились в /home от кде и подтягиваются гномом?

Comment: @mamol, поидей не должно... но можешь создать нового пользователя для проверки...